# How to pass arguments to a callback in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I have a function that does some logic then runs a success callback function or a fail callback function.

Here is the code:

```
some_function() ->
    ArgumentsForCallback = [],
    check_some_condition(Input, fun success_callback/1, fun fail_callback/1).
```

How do I pass `ArgumentsForCallback` to the callbacks?

Comment: Can you please post the source of `check_some_condition`? Does it call the callback functions with 0 arguments?

Comment: You are right, callback functions are called without arguments which seems to be a wrong way. Should I pass arguments to `check_some_condition` and then call callback functions with them from inside `check_some_condition` function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. Pass the argument to `check_some_condition` and make that function send the argument to the callbacks:

   ```
   check_some_condition(Input, ArgumentsForCallback, Success, Fail) ->
       Success(ArgumentsForCallback).

   some_function() ->
       ArgumentsForCallback = [],
       check_some_condition(Input, ArgumentsForCallback, fun success_callback/1, fun fail_callback/1).
   ```
2. Send anonymous functions to `check_some_condition`:

   ```
   check_some_condition(Input,
       fun() -> success_callback(ArgumentsForCallback) end,
       fun() -> fail_callback(ArgumentsForCallback) end).
   ```